# NTPD: drifts away from system clock

Tags: linux, ntp, rhel-5

Using RHEL 5.x on a workstation.

I set the clock using `ntpdate 0.us.pool.ntp.org` and then start NTPD using `service ntpd start`. (this also happens at boot). Watching this over the next 20-30 minutes it appears to run at about 1/2 speed. After 20 minutes the clock is ~10 minutes behind.

Calling `ntpq -p` (after 20 minutes) shows three servers (coming from pool) all of which still have `.INIT.` in the **refid** column.

Looking at the system log shows an uneventful startup for NTPD. No errors to speak of.

Calling `hwclock` shows the correct current time.

Contents of `/etc/ntp.conf`:

```
restrict 127.0.0.1

server 0.us.pool.ntp.org
server 1.us.pool.ntp.org
server 2.us.pool.ntp.org

driftfile /var/lib/ntp/drift
statsdir /var/lib/ntp
```

Looking at `nmap -p123 -sU -P0 servername` I see `123/udp open|filtered ntp`.

Not sure where else to look to diagnose this. Suggestions?

EDIT: `iburst` didn't seem to have any effect.

I tried running NTPD using `-ddd` to see what's going on. It starts out getting packets pretty steadily and then slows to a crawl. After 5 minutes my clock is 3 minutes behind. It was set initially using `ntpdate`.

Comment: Are you doing any sort of virtualisation?

Comment: No virtualization.

Comment: Add `iburst` to your server declarations.

Comment: Try a different pool, take the hard drive out and put it in a different machine and see if the issue continues. My money is on a bad network card in the workstation.

Comment: It looks like you have a firewall blocking port 123.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that running the NTPd service on your box doesn't necessarily mean that your box uses it.  You'll want to run a NTP client on your system (it looks like it's configured properly).  Since you've mentioned ntpdate, assumption is that you're not acutally running NTP as a client.  To fix, you can either run ntp as a client service or set up a cron job to run ntp (or ntpdate) periodically. Additional reading: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/rhel-fedora-centos-configure-ntp-client-server/

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your ntp does not recieve packets from the pool. Try running `sudo tcpdump -n -i <ifname> port 123` after you have restarted ntpd. You should see packets going both ways, if not, then you have a firewall problem (which can not keep track/state of UDP-connections).